# When I importing gujarati data using csv file that time data show like?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I am using db2 database and when I importing gujarati data that time data show some symbols. 
I try to set UTF-8 but still it's show symbol. 
Db2-server platform is windows.
How to importing gujarati data.?

[image]

Comment: Add details on how you perform the import. What command, what parameters, how does the raw data look like, what is the table definition, ...?

Comment: Also, are you sure that application you’re querying the database with is capable of displaying the data, and the font that it’s using has the correct glyphs for the code points in the database?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from the problem description whether there is an issue with the client or the database, so I will show universal steps to troubleshoot an issue of this kind.
I understand that your intention is to store the data as UTF-8 and [Db2 documentation says](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.nls.doc/doc/r0004565.html):

> The following Indic scripts are supported through Unicode: Hindi, Gujarati, Kannada, Konkani, Marathi, Punjabi, Sanskrit, Tamil and Telugu.

i.e. we can use any UTF-8 database (code page 1252) for Gujarati. [It has 91 code points assigned according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gujarati_(Unicode_block)), from  U+0A81 to U+0AD0. This implies internally [they will need 3 bytes for storage encoded as UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Design) (which also means first byte will be always 0xE).

Let's try to use "ગુજરાતી" (Gujarati) as an example.
It consists of 7 characters:

```
U+0A97 GUJARATI LETTER GA       utf-8 0xE0AA97
U+0AC1 GUJARATI VOWEL SIGN U    utf-8 0xE0AB81
U+0A9C GUJARATI LETTER JA       utf-8 0xE0AA9C
U+0AB0 GUJARATI LETTER RA       utf-8 0xE0AAB0
U+0ABE GUJARATI VOWEL SIGN AA   utf-8 0xE0AABE
U+0AA4 GUJARATI LETTER TA       utf-8 0xE0AAA4
U+0AC0 GUJARATI VOWEL SIGN II   utf-8 0xE0AB80
```

Let's test:

```
db2 "create table gujarati_tab(c1 int, c2 varchar(10 codeunits32))"
db2 "insert into gujarati_tab values(1, 'ગુજરાતી')"
```

To make sure data is stored properly we can examine the binary structure of our column:

```
db2 "select hex(c2) from gujarati_tab"

1                                          
-------------------------------------------
E0AA97E0AB81E0AA9CE0AAB0E0AABEE0AAA4E0AB80
```

Now you can split that into 7 3-byte structures each matching expected set of bytes for given characters:

```
E0AA97 E0AB81 E0AA9C E0AAB0 E0AABE E0AAA4 E0AB80
```

which implies data is stored correctly in the database. If there is still an issue on the client end, it will be strictly a problem of client application that is not interpreting correct UFT-8 data returned by the database.