# Data too long Error for a column of type Varchar(600) in db2(Windows and 10.0.22 version)

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have set a column size of type Varchar of size 600. But i get the below error while updating the table.

```
[Code: -404, SQL State: 22001]  THE SQL STATEMENT SPECIFIES A STRING THAT IS TOO LONG. SQLCODE=-404, SQLSTATE=22001, DRIVER=4.25.1301
```

I am using a update query as shown below.

```
update test set description= <here i am passing the description of charachters length 600> where id=1;
```

The above specified error doesn't appear if i pass the description of charachter count 597 charachters. But the error appears if the charachters count is greater than 597 even tough i have set the column size as 600. Is there any specific explanation for this?

Comment: Are you assuming that each character requires one byte of storage? Check the CCSID of the column/table / database codepage.  Always specify your Db2-server *operating-system* and Db2-version when asking for help (Z/OS, i-series, Linux/Unix/Windows) or use appropriate tags.

Comment: Yes i am assuming 1 character as 1 byte of storage.

Comment: That may be a false assumption, depending on the database-codepage and territory, and your application codepage.

Answer (score 2):

A quick test:

```
db2 "create table varchar_test(c1 int, c2 varchar(10))"
db2 "insert into varchar_test values (1, '0123456789')"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
```

obviously I can insert 10-byte string here. But if I would replace the last character with multi-byte UTF character "ą" (2 bytes in utf-8), it fails:

```
db2 "insert into varchar_test values (2, '012345678ą')"
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0433N  Value "012345678ą" is too long.  SQLSTATE=22001
```

with one fewer it is OK:

```
db2 "insert into varchar_test values (2, '01234567ą')"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
```

so I can test now:

```
db2 "select c1, length(c2) c2_len_bytes,CHARACTER_LENGTH(c2) c2_char_len, hex(c2) c2_hex from varchar_test" 

C1          C2_LEN_BYTES C2_CHAR_LEN C2_HEX              
----------- ------------ ----------- --------------------
          1           10          10 30313233343536373839
          2           10           9 3031323334353637C485
```

-> it confirms that the second row is 10 bytes in size but has 9 characters. 
I suggest to repeat the same exercise for the longest string you can fit and see whether indeed you have only single-byte characters in your VARCHAR. For a more detailed examination of utf-8 characters in Db2 database you can review my answer here:
[When I importing gujarati data using csv file that time data show like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58092941/when-i-importing-gujarati-data-using-csv-file-that-time-data-show-like)
(nothing Db2 specific there, just a regular "utf-8 troubleshooting")